# I need to check if Current user is Author to Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to write a conditional statement (in pseudo below to explain)

```
IF current logged in user is 'Author' to a custom-post-type called 'farmers' {
// Do something
} else {
// Do something else
}
```

My code effort so far is

```
<?php
// Global variable for current user ID
$user_ID;

// Create a new WP query object           
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'farmers',
'author' => $user_ID
));

// Get all the current user posts from the query object
$posts = $my_query->posts;

IF $posts = 0 {
// Do something
} else {
// Do Something else
} ?>
```

User can have the role "Author" in the system, but not necessarily have any posts. So I need to check the condition that this Author actually has a post. I am just not sure how to write that IF statement at the end of the code and looking for some help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
$query="select * from posts where type='farmers'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$valid=false;
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
$valid=true;
}


if($_SESSION["id"]==$posts["id"]){
//your code
}else{
//your code
}
```

or

```
if(mysql_num_rows($posts)>0){
// user have post
 }
```

Comment: did this not work, but I made an update to my original post to show u the code I am using so far...it is the IF statement I can't figure out

Comment: @Redwall you should check that posted user_id is equals to current user id? if matches than it shows current user has post...

Comment: yeah sorry, I have that in my global php at the top of my page `$userID = $current_user->ID; //logged in user's ID` - it is my IF statment that is wrong. `IF $posts = 0` what I want to write here in English is IF this Author has a post, or maybe IF posts is TRUE

Comment: @Redwall can you show me the exact query which you are making to database? or which values are you selecting?

Comment: I updated my original question with the code I am using, do u see it?

Comment: @Redwall what have you changed?

Comment: I added the code sample I have started with. You can see the query there? I am not great at PHP so I might have misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way...

```
   if($user_session_id == $author_id) {
    // Do something
    } else {
    // Do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to check a specific post you can check if

```
get_current_user_id() == get_post($your_post_id)->post_author
```

Or in the WordPress loop you can check if

```
get_current_user_id() == $post->post_author
```

And for completeness sake, the following answers the original question. This checks if the current user is the author of any post belonging to a custom post type; in this case `farmers`

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'farmers',
  'author' => get_current_user_id()
));

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Do Something else
}
```